# unable to make a facebook post using iMacros

Tags: imacros

I made a script on iMacros using normal recording mode to make a wall post, but it doesn't seem to be recording the content to pasted on my wall though..

This is the code I wrote using the normal mode

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:_1mf<SP>_1mj EXTRACT=TXT
```

The above is able to extract contents from the post message field, however I'm unable to make it type contents into the same field... :(

Now, I have tried using EVENT recording mode and I am still facing issues.. Here is my code:

```
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="#u_0_16" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP POINT="(386,118)"
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#js_gy>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV" CHAR="d"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#js_gy>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" CHARS="Pasting Sample Content"
```

What am i doing wrong? :O :O

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're still facing issues. So for example, try to play these lines:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:_1mf<SP>_1mj EXTRACT=TXT
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="DIV[CLASS='_1mf _1mj']" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="DIV[CLASS='_1mf _1mj']" CHARS={{!EXTRACT}}
```

Comment: still the same buddy... :(
it just doesn't post anything into the post area.. :(

i get this error: 

RuntimeError: element specified by DIV[CLASS='_1mf _1mj'] not found, line: 1

Comment: okay, I ran it multiple times, still not luck.. although i notice now that if i manually click on the "What's on your mind?" field and then run the script it works.. else it doesn't... :(

Getting this error: RuntimeError: element specified by DIV[CLASS='_1mf _1mj'] not found, line: 3

URL GOTO=www.facebook.com
WAIT SECONDS=1
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="DIV[CLASS='_1mf _1mj']" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS=1
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="DIV[CLASS='_1mf _1mj']" CHARS="SampleText"